# passing sku to Sagepay using Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, skus

my clients uses Sagepay for his bookeeping and wants the website (using Magento and the Ebizmarts Extension v3.0.19.1) to pass the sku to the Sagepay portal along with the current customer details.

Can anyone advise how I go about doing this?

I have this link from Sagepay - http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/28/37/items-not-deducting-from-your-stock - but I'm not sure whereabouts in the code I would need to add the sku in order to pass it to Sagepay?

any advice welcome.

thanks in advance

Comment: the SKU is already being sent on the basket, if you need it in a special format you might want to edit [this code](https://github.com/ebizmarts/sage-pay-suite-ce/blob/master/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Model/Api/Payment.php#L1439)

Comment: Hi Pablo

thanks very much for this.

The adviser from Sagepay said the following in their email:

For your basket contents to pull through to Sage Accounts, you need to be adding 'product codes' for your items, into your accounts software, and then referencing these product codes, in the Basket field when the transaction is sent to Sage Pay.

So if the sku is already being sent then we don't need to do anything else from the website side of things?

thanks

Comment: you should be okay then, make sure to use Sage50 basket and not BasketXML on the module settings.

Comment: great, thanks Pablo

one other thing - is the p & p value also pulled across to Sage like the sku?

Comment: p & p? can you please elaborate?

Comment: sorry, shipping value.